# MySQL insert table1 update table2, subquery or transaction?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert or update, then insert a new log into another table.

I'm running a nifty little query to pull information from a staging table into other tables, something like

Insert into
select
on duplicate key update

What I'd like to do without php, or triggers (the lead dev doesn't like em, and I'm not that familiar with them either) is insert a new record into a logging table. Needed for reporting on what data was updated or inserted and on what table.

Any hints or examples?

Note: I was doing this with php just fine, although it was taking about 4 hours to process on 50K rows. Using the laravel php framework, looping over each entry in staging update 4 other tables with the data and log for each one was equalling 8 queries for each row (this was using laravel models not raw sql). I was able to optimise by pushing logs into an array and batch processing. But you can't beat 15sec processing time in mysql by bypassing all that throughput. Now I'm hooked on doing awesome things the sql way.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're asking. You obviously already know how to do an insert so just do that to log the update/insert?

Comment: basically I'd like to loop over all rows in one table. And be able to write multiple queries for each row. I'll do some more googling on transactions, I know you can specify multiple queries in there although I think they're for the all or nothing approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need executing more than one query statement. I refer to use transaction then trigger to guarantee [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) (part of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). Bellow code is sample for [MySql transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html):

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ...
INSERT ...
DELETE ...
Other query statement
COMMIT;
```

Statements inside transaction will be executed all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do two things (insert the base row and insert a log row), you'll need two statements.  The second can (and should) be a trigger.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll push for the use of a trigger.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the only way I can achieve what I was imagining is to use a stored procedure with a cursor. Unfortunately I don't think that'll fly

Comment: Maybe if you figured out why the lead dev doesn't like triggers, we could help you convince him/her.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a Trigger, it is often used for Logging purposes